# how do I re-enable "unresponsive script" warning in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have disabled the warning with "do not ask again" check box, now I want to get the warning again. How can I re-enable it?

Comment: Wait, so when I click "don't ask me again" and then press "Stop plugin", it doesn't just stop the plugin automatically without asking me?  Grr ambiguous dialog boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the page about:config in a new tab, and reset the pref `dom.max_script_run_time`:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.max_script_run_time

Answer (score 4):

The "Don't ask me again" checkbox only applies to the currently running script.

If you haven't ticked it, the warning will pop up approximately every `dom.max_script_run_time` seconds while the script is still running.

Simply refresh the page (or run another script) and you should get the warning again if your script is taking too long.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `about:config` page.

In my Firefox there are now three script variables that are probably changed when checking the checkbox:

```
dom.max_child_script_run_time
dom.max_chrome_script_run_time
dom.max_script_run_time
```

Just type `script_run` in the search box and it shows just these three. Right-click each one of them that's **bold** and choose 'Reset'.